# XmlElement Inheritance

Tags: c#, xml, inheritance

I would like to know if it's possible to inherit from an XmlElement field such as

```
public class A{
          [XmlElement(ElementName = "Something", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string Something{ get; set; }
}

public class B: A
{
}
```

And while using class B objects, could I have the Something XmlElement field that I could manipulate by doing things such as a try parse to make a Int32 ?

Thank you

//**EDITS**

Here's something that I would do with this xml element field in an other class.

```
public class B: A, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
         public Int32? TimerValueFromApi
        {
            get 
            { 
                int timerValueFromApi;
                return int.TryParse(base.Something, out timerValueFromApi) ? (int?) timerValueFromApi : null; 

            }
            set
            {
                base.Something = value.HasValue ? value.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : "0";
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TimerValueFromApi");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you demonstrate that last bit in a code example?

Comment: @Mark Cidade I've added a piece of logic I'd like to do.

Comment: I was told that the inheritance would stick either way. It's like another regular field. I'm going to do a bit of digging on my own later and then post a final answer to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works:

```
var xml = "<B><Something>5</Something></B>";
var b = (B) new XmlSerializer(typeof(B)).Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
Console.WriteLine(b.TimerValueFromApi); // outputs "5"
```

Comment: exactly something this useful that I was looking for. Works pretty good. You're awesome

Answer (score 1):

You can use some AfterDeserialization action like this:

```
public interface IDeserializable
{
    void OnDeserialize();
}

public class A
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Something", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Something { get; set; }
}

public class B : A, IDeserializable
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public Int32 SomethingInt32
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void OnDeserialize()
    {
        SomethingInt32 = Int32.Parse(Something);
    }
}

public class C
{
    public void Deserialize()
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(B));
        var b = ser.Deserialize(streamOrStringData) as B;
        b.OnDeserialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: your idea works too, but it's a bit more code than I would like to use. But it's still an acceptable answer! :)